# Spfx web part to show task list on modern sharepoint UI

Tags: spfx-webparts, task-list, modern-pages, modern-team-site

I am looking to leverage team sites for one of my projects. Since modern UI only supports custom lists in web part view, I am looking for some help on how Spfx can be used to show task list web part in modern UI.

If someone has developed a solution, please share.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please, use this link for support a develop solution for Tasks at Modern Share Point
https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/325347-office-com-home-page/suggestions/32864941-create-webpart-to-embed-sharepoint-tasks-list-and

Answer (score 1):

We used this task list in the past: https://github.com/devoooo4u/spfx-task-list-web-part
[image]
(Picture is from the GitHub repo.)

But it might need updating since things are moving so fast.

Answer (score 0):

If the task list os on the site in which the webpage is created for - it can be done using the "embed" option - copy & paste the url into the embed webpart & your done